# migrate WSP from SP2013 to SP2019 - using power shell but getting error as '16' is not a valid version

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2019

I have extracted all the WSP from SP2013 environment and want to deploy it to SP2019.
I am using "**Add-SPSolution**" and "**Install-SPSolutio**n" commands.
will this work? Or will be having any issue in future?

I am using below command

Install-SPSolution –Identity "WSP Name".wsp –WebApplication "Site Url" –GACDeployment **-CompatibilityLevel "16"**

and getting error as - " **16 is not a valid version** "

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps

Look at `-CompatibilityLevel` parameter and valid values.

Valid values are:

--14

--15

--14,15